# How to loop through an Object Properties?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

I have an object that contains some properties. How do I loop to search out every property and it’s value?

Below is an example object...

```
var person = { firstname: "Aleko", lastname: "Kas", age: 28 };
```

Comment: use for in loop

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: Thanks, I just tried a for in and it worked

for (var x in person) {
    console.log(x + ": " + person[x])
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution using a for loop:

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "Aleko",
  lastname: "Kas",
  age: 28
};

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(person).length; i++) {
  console.log(Object.keys(person)[i] + " : " + Object.values(person)[i]);
}
```